# Access to STL lists of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, list, stl

I wonder how to get access to element of list that contains pointers to objects. I want to achieve that without dereferencing. Propably it will be much easier if i just show what i want. So I have list:

```
list<ObjectClass*> nameOfObject;
```

and I have method:

```
bool collision(list<ObjectClass*>::iterator&);
```

And inside definition of that method I have:

```
{
    if((*nameOfObject)->getSprite()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

What i want is to getSprite without needing to dereference nameOfObject inside method, so something like that:

```
{
    if((nameOfObject)->getSprite()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Everything that i tried is not working. I thought that it would be easy but i really don;t get it. Any ideas? I will add that list has to contain pointer to the objects, because of polimorphysm.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to avoid dereferencing? You have a pointer, you have to dereference it one way or another to access contained method/properties.

Comment: `bool collision(list<ObjectClass*>::iterator&);` doesn't make sense to me. you should either take a `ObjectClass*`(or `ObjectClass&`) or a pair of iterator(which should not limited to `std::list`, but it's another story)...

Comment: @yeputons i wanted to use templates here, and it's the only situation where i have pointer inside list, so body of my function is different

Comment: @appleapple could you write more details? Propably i've done it in stupid way, and it would be awasome to make it better ;)

Comment: If the list will only contain non-null pointer, `std::ref` may work better than pointers https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper

Comment: @Tojmak if only you can provide more detail, otherwise I'm just guessing. see also: [mcve]

Comment: @appleapple i think your guesses are correct. I tried to make it `ObjectClass&`, but with that i have problem how to use that method. Previously i had something like that: `for (int j = 0; j < size(); j++){ if(collision(Map, j, itr)) { do something }}`
and `itr` is from other loop: `for (auto itr = ObjectClass.begin(); itr != ObjectClass.end(); itr++)` so after i changed `list<ObjectClass*>, to list<ObjectClass&>, i've got an error that no instance of overloaded function collision() matches the argument list (...)
I hope that i provided enaugh details now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually don't pass *single* iterator around.

If you want single object, pass single object (whether by reference or pointer)

---

I write an example code, hope it helps.

- `fIter` is probably what most close to what you currently have
- `f` is demonstrate you can iterate collection without directly use iterator

---

```
//
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/63156916/5980430
//

#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class ObjectClass{
   public:
   int spriteID;
   int getSprite(){return spriteID;}
};


//your *collision* function
void collision(ObjectClass& obj){
   std::cout << obj.getSprite() << '\n';
}

void f(std::list<ObjectClass>& objs){
    for (auto& obj : objs){
        collision(obj);
    }
}

//even with iterator, you dereference it before pass in other functions
void fIter(std::list<ObjectClass>& objs){
    for (auto it = objs.begin(); it != objs.end(); ++it){
        collision(*it);
    }
}

int main(){
   std::list<ObjectClass> objects;
   objects.push_back({1});
   objects.push_back({2});
   objects.push_back({3});
   
   f(objects);
    
   fIter(objects);
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/SgI5ibjaIXd644DH

Comment: btw since eerorika's answer already have upvote, I'd also post this answer

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> list<ObjectClass*>::iterator&
> ```

It's unclear why iterator is passed by reference.

> ```
> *nameOfObject
> ```

This is ill-formed because `std::list` doesn't have indirection operator. I suspect that you may have shadowed that variable, and forgotten to include the shadowing variable in the example.

> What i want is to getSprite without needing to dereference nameOfObject inside method,

Then you need to have an instance of a class with `getSprite` member function in the class rather than a pointer/iterator to such. If you do have a pointer/iterator, then there is no way to access the pointed object through the pointer without indirection.

> so something like that:
>
> ```
> (nameOfObject)->getSprite()
> ```

That **does** dereference `nameOfObject`. `->` is the indirecting member access operator. It is also ill-formed with a list.

> Any ideas?

Avoid wanting impossible things ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `->` is *defined* in terms of `*` and `.`, such that `(nameOfObject)->getSprite()` is *by definition* equivalent to `(*nameOfObject).getSprite()`